# how to make the navigation button top left corner of the navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an programatically made nav button in navigation bar, I am trying to make image on the button(as like back button) and i made it, but my problem is, the button not appearing on the left corner, it appearing after some space.

```
 let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 40)
    button.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_left_2x"), for: .normal)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButton]
```

please help me to acheive the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all code by :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_left_2x"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourSelector))  
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Back"
```